# sending UTF chars to java from c++ using jni

Tags: java, c++, character-encoding, java-native-interface

I want to send Hangul (Korean symbols using UTF) text from C to JAVA.
But JAVA gets incorrect results
Example:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_get_1term
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject, jint termInd)
{
    const char *str = "음뮤원음직음원샘";
    return (env)->NewStringUTF(str);
}
```

but in that case JAVA got incorrect string.

I couldn't find answer to my question in other posts, if there is same question please give me link to them

Comment: Doesn't Java use UTF-16BE? While your C source code has entirely platform-dependent behaviour.

Comment: Internally a java char or a jni jchar is unsigned 16bit type. But NewStringUTF expects a UTF8 char pointer. So this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this (taken and adapted from [here](http://www.anyang-window.com.cn/between-java-and-c-transmission-through-jni-chinese-string-and-hash-issues/)):

```
jstring WindowsToJstring(JNIEnv* pEnv, char* cstr) {
   jstring retJstring = NULL;
   int slen = strlen(cstr);
   int length = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, (LPCSTR)cstr, slen, NULL, 0 );
   unsigned short* tempbuffer = (unsigned short *)malloc( length*2 + 1 );
   MultiByteToWideChar( CP_ACP, 0, (LPCSTR)cstr, slen, (LPWSTR)tempbuffer, length );
   retJstring = (pEnv)->NewString((jchar*)tempbuffer, length );
   free( tempbuffer );
   return retJstring;
}
```

**EDIT** As correctly noted by  @Kerrek SB this is a Windows only solution

Comment: Who said the OP is working on Windows? (Although I admit that Java is very platform independent when restricted to run only on Windows :-).)

Comment: Any idea how to do this for Unix platforms?